# What's a fast ideal hash function for int32?

Tags: c, optimization, hash

I need ideal (no collisions) hash function to map int to int of same size. The simplest way is to swap positions of some bits, but maybe there is some good fast realisations with small operations count and easily changeable hash seed?
Maybe use some fast symmetric cipher? x86 has `AES` instructions. I don't need portability, so something using `SSE` or other x86 specific instructions for acceleration would be great? Because hashing should be very fast.

Comment: Why would you want to map `int` to `int`, that doesn't make any sense at all. Is it because the array has gaps? There could be other solutions based on arithmetics perhaps!

Comment: Yes - can you explain what you need this hash function for? Otherwise the identity function (just map "x" to "x") sounds like it fits your requirements - it maps integers to integers of the same size, with no collisions, and it's very very fast :)

Comment: @psmears You missed one more *very*.

Comment: @iharob: True, but only if you optimise it *really* well ;-)

Comment: I implementing a open addressed map and if input values are clustered I need to skip a lot for finding element. I want such hash function to make clustered values randomly distributed

Comment: No, I'm currently using int directly as key. First x (mapsize 2<<x ) bits are used as key, if there is no record there then key is incremented.
But now I'm thinking that maybe I should fast hash like crc32(because intel has sse instruction for it), I realized that there is no need to use ideal hashing here

Comment: Take a look at gperf on UNIX systems. https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

Comment: Since the `int` you read are "clustered", post their clustering attributes.  Mostly even, digits tend to be low values, match zip codes, what??

Comment: A simple un-clustering is to `% table size` and insure `table_size` is a prime number.  This will not harm a good hash.  It often helps a poor hash.  YMMV.

Comment: My ints are ipv4 addresses, they may be distributed in different ways - lot of queries from same ip/ips, totally random ips, or ascending/descending

Comment: FYI, you might want to look at [the implementation notes for CPython's `dict` type](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/dictnotes.txt). While many components are specific to Python's usage of `dict`s (that needs specific behaviors and features a normal "data storage" hash table doesn't need), the optimizations for open addressing to allow jumping around the table when possible while still exploiting the fact that reading part of a cache line makes reading the rest cheap might be useful to you.

Comment: >jumping around the table when possible while still exploiting the fact that reading part of a cache line makes reading the rest cheap 

This is interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks.
Currently my code is based on libdynamic map, it outperforms other maps like std C++ containers because it's simple and cache friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably get better results using a simple hash like [FNV32-1A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function).

Complex instructions like `crc32`, `clmul`, `aes`, etc...  have higher throughputs, but they can also have higher latencies.  By themselves, they won't necessarily give you a better distribution either.

One of the other things you should consider is the cost of a collision versus the hash function.  Linear probe should generally perform well up to a reasonable number of probes since 16 values will fit on a single cache line.  The CPU will likely be able to hide the access cost as well by predicting cache accesses.

It's also worth considering is the trade-off between the occupancy ratio and table size.  Sometimes it's more effective to just double the table size.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that there is no need to use ideal hashing and simple hash will work. Currently I tried crc32 and it gave me 10x performance increase on clustered values by decreasing miss count 10000x times, now performance fits my needs and is about 20-30M queries per core. Maybe I'll benchmark other functions too.

Comment: @user1940679 If I remember correctly `crc32` has a throughput of a cycle, but a latency of something like three cycles.

Comment: Can your recommend some good reading about intel low level optimisation? I'm new in such things. If I have several instructions not using crc32 data then latency shouldn't make difference, yes? I also tried hash from answer below, crc32 instruction is faster, so I think there is no way to outperform it in int2int hashing

Comment: @user1940679 The intel [manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) are pretty comprehensive.  The pipeline might be able to hide the latency for the `crc32` instruction, but it depends on the workload.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t hash( uint32_t value )
{
    return( value * 0xdeece66d + 0xb );
}
```

Comment: While it's an answer, I see no reason why it's better or worse than any other `ax + b` approach to hashing (and without knowing more about the inputs, you could just as easily use `value` directly, or bit rotate it a bit and get the same effect).

Comment: @ShadowRanger It generates a 1 to 1 mapping for any input size. In other words, if you limit the `value` to 10-bits and mask the return to 10-bits, then you get a 1 to 1 mapping between 10 bit values. By contrast, a bad choice of multiplier and addend, e.g. `return( value * 8 + 4 )` does not generate a 1 to 1 mapping.

Comment: Well, yes. But I'm pretty sure that literally any prime multiplier will work just fine; one magic prime is no better than another, in general.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Those particular numbers date back to the Commodore Amiga, and are currently in use in [Java's java.util.Random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use)

Comment: @user3386109 For a Linear Congruential Generator with m = 48 bits, and with another 5<<32 added in, and taking bits 16 .. 48 as the output bits. Why does that make it a good hash function for a 32 bit int to a 32 bit int? Would one of the 32 bit ones not be a better choice?

Comment: @abligh The answer is based on the same theory as an LCG, but it is not an LCG. In particular, my answer has m=32 bits, and there's no *"taking bit 16..48"*. The point is that if you limit the input to N bits and mask the output to N bits, then you get a one-to-one mapping of input to output, where the output values are randomized with respect to the input. Hence, if the input is clustered, then the output is unlikely to be clustered.

Comment: Given that OP is taking this mod something, adding a constant does not help, that just "rotates" the table indices, it doesn't spread out clusters. So just the multiplication is equally good