# Always Generate the Same Numbers to be Discarded Given a Percentage

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I'm working with a very long list of numbers, say 1.5 billion. I need a way to specify a percentage of numbers that I want to keep, and the rest discard. Now I know I can use a Random Number Generator to randomly decide if I should keep it or not, but the problem is that I need the numbers to keep/discard to always be the same. Meaning, if I run the program and it decides to discard indexes 2, 5, and 10, the next time I run the program, it must discard 2, 5, and 10 as well. This is very important.

I'm also facing an issue with memory. To generate a huge list of bools to determine which numbers are discarded and which are not (if we decided to go that way, for example), the profiler says the program uses around 15gb of memory, which is already too much considering I have yet another list of 1.5 billion numbers. Here's my code for that if that matters:

```
        static bool[] GenerateShouldAddList(int totalCombos, decimal percentToAdd)
        {
            Random RNG = new Random();
            bool[] bools = new bool[totalCombos];
            int percent = (int)(percentToAdd * 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < totalCombos; i++)
            {
                int randNum = RNG.Next(0, 101);
                bools[i] = randNum < percent;
            }

            return bools;
        }
```

So I'm thinking, to avoid making a huge list, is there a way to make a function that will take in the index number (say index 5364), the total numbers (1.5 billion) and the percentage that you want to keep, and then return to me whether I should add that specific index or not? And if I run each index one at a time through that function, I should only be left with the percentage of numbers I specified. And most importantly, this function should always return the same result for the same index (if the totalNumbers and the percentage don't change). I'm thinking this isn't possible, but I also have hope there's people on here that are much smarter than me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using random with *seed*, e.g. `Random RNG = new Random(12345);` it will generate random but repeating sequence

Comment: Try *reservoir sampling*, in this case ypu don't have to load the entire array into memory, enumeration is enough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting a function that takes in an index and a percentage and always gives the same result of whether or not that index should be kept, but in a sufficiently random way. This can be achieved by using a hashing algorithm so that the input is always hashed to the same output but in a random way. I tested the below with 10,000 indexes and at 10% it kept 1006 at 50% it kept 4998 and at 90% it kept 9006, so the percentages kept are fairly close to what was requested while still being random.

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static class ToKeepOrNotToKeep
{
    private static readonly MD5 _md5 = MD5.Create();

    public static bool AtIndex(int index, double percentToKeep)
    {
        var byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(index);
        var hash = _md5.ComputeHash(byteArray);
        //I know that the hash is 16 bytes, and here we are converting
        //only the first 8 bytes to a ulong, but it's still random and
        //should work just as well as if we used all 16 bytes for our
        //threshold test
        var number = BitConverter.ToUInt64(hash, 0);
        var threshold = ulong.MaxValue * percentToKeep;

        if (number <= threshold)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

There is some overhead running cryptographic hashes like this, so if you are concerned about performance I ran a benchmark on this process using `BenchmarkDotNet` on my laptop running an 11th gen i7 11370H and on average it took 220 ns to run this. At the quantities you are talking about, 1.5 billion operations would consume about 5.5 minutes of CPU time just running this method. If that 5.5 minutes is a concern for you then you could find simpler and faster hashing methods.

I was curious about how much of a performance boost you would see by switching to a simpler hashing algorithm like the FNV-1a that was suggested in a comment, so I implemented it below

```cs
public static class ToKeepOrNotToKeep
{
    public static bool AtIndex(int index, double percentToKeep)
    {
        var byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(index);
        var hash = getHash(byteArray);
        var threshold = ulong.MaxValue * percentToKeep;

        if (hash <= threshold)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private ulong getHash(byte[] input)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            ulong hash = 14695981039346656037;

            foreach(var b in input)
            {
                hash ^= b;
                hash *= 1099511628211;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmarking this version, it was much much faster than the MD5 cryptogrphic hash and on average it took about 10 ns to run per method call which over 1.5 billion operations would be 15 seconds instead of 5.5 minutes, but the distribution is a lot less random. To roughly compare the distribution of the MD5 hash version vs. the FNV1-a version here are the first 100 indexes where 1 means keep and 0 means discard and it's run at 50%

`MD5 1111011001110001001011001110110010000011000101110000001000100010100111110010111010011111000011000100`

`FNV-1a 1000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000`

The FNV-1a version feels a lot more cyclical and so if randomness in the selection is important to you, then the extra overhead of the MD5 hash method may be worth it to you. If the chunking is acceptable and you want speed, then the FNV-1a version will be much much faster.

Comment: Wow thank you for the update, I didn't realize there could be a faster hashing algorithm. Still, my original method was taking quite a bit of time (30mins +) so it seems like an improvement. For my purposes, the chunking doesn't actually matter so I might go with FNV-1a.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a lot of items, I suggest working with enumerations, `IEnumerable<T>` instead of arrays
(which can well be not fit memory). Another requirement - repeatable selection - can be solved with
*seed*: we create `new Random(seed)` and have the same sequence again and again:

```
static IEnumerable<bool> GenerateShouldAddList(int totalCombos, decimal percentToAdd) {
  Random RNG = new Random(789); // Whatever seed you like here 

  double threshold = percentToAdd / 100.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < totalCombos; ++i) 
    yield return RNG.NextDouble() < threshold;
}
```

If you insist on having an *array*, you can add `.ToArray()`, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

bool[] array = GenerateShouldAddList(10000, 5.0m).ToArray();
```

But I really doubt if you should do this.

Comment: This works perfectly! I didn't know I could simply add a seed to Random. Thank you for your answer. I am however going with TJ Rockefeller's answer since it would not require me to generate a list or enumeration (I need to save as much space as possible), and it would work in a parallel for loop which is something I was considering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a function which takes an index and a percent value, and returns a boolean value, the result of which would be same whether you call `is_kept(index=2, percent=50)` before or after `is_kept(index=50000, percent=50)` and don't want to store anything.

For this, I'd generate a hash of the index, and then treat that as a number, divide by the maximum hash and compare with the percent. The would given random-like behaviour without having to allocate any memory for state or a long list of flags.

Comment: This is actually a great answer, but without including code, it's very hard for someone like me who has no experience working with hashes to figure out exactly how to implement.

Comment: True, but there are plenty of other answers here about 'how to hash a single integer', such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/33816270 or you can use the accepted answer if you don't care about performance